# Xcode display all methods in jump bar

Tags: xcode

I have an Objective-C class that implements NSCoding. The methods' signatures are as follows.

```
- ( id ) initWithCoder:( NSCoder * ) in
```

and

```
- ( void ) encodeWithCoder:( NSCoder * ) out
```

and it works.

These methods show up in the class hierarchy (on the left) but do not show up in the **jump bar** (on top) when I click there. You can also get to this using *Show Document Items* (default Ctrl+6) but that shows the same menu with methods missing.

I also note that in other files the same happens for these NSCoding methods, they are missing from the jump bar.

Does Xcode (9.1) hide these? I can't find how or where to turn them on. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Have you tried to usual voodoo (delete Derived Data, clean, restart Xcode, restart computer)?

Comment: Thanks dasdom - have tried but to no avail. Also tried on my MBP where I have a copy of the project. Xcode stubbornly refuses to show those methods, which I discovered just as I was looking for them ... it seems like some built in thing so I wonder how to turn it off ...

Comment: FWIW. This is inside a .m file with an interface section followed by some class methods and then these two instance methods followed by more instance methods. All methods except these two show up. I prefixed these two with a #pragma mark but they still do not show up. It 'feels' as if Xcode is hiding them deliberately - because they override NSCoding? - and I was hoping somebody knows why or where to turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let me answer my own question. When I implemented those NSCoding methods, as you can see, I used in and out for the arguments. Now I expected the compiler to complain if I use **in** since there is an Xcode keyword? when you do fast enumeration that is also called in. However, since the compiler never complained and since it reads really easy if you use **in** as the name of the decoder (and **out** for the encoder) I kept it that way.

Now, I note that if I change the **in** to something else and funny enough the **out** as well the methods show up in the jump bar. Is **out** a keyword in Objective-C? I don't know but if I change it then the method shows up.